# How to add ARRAY column to Spark table (using ALTER TABLE)?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, delta-lake

I am trying to add a new column of Array Type to the table with default value.

```
%sql
ALTER TABLE testdb.tabname ADD COLUMN new_arr_col ARRAY DEFAULT ['A','B','C'];
```

But it says that the data type in not supported

```
Error in SQL statement: ParseException: 
DataType array is not supported.(line 1, pos 54)

== SQL ==
ALTER TABLE testdb.dim_category ADD COLUMN c_cat_area ARRAY
```

So, there is no way we can add an array column directly to the table? Kindly assist me on this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This `DEFAULT` keyword makes me think you use Databricks (not a vanilla Delta Lake on Spark 3.2)?

Comment: This is Delta lake spark. Spark v3.2.1. Is this way of applying default value wrong?

Comment: I don't think `DEFAULT` is supported in Delta Lake OSS. It will only work in Databricks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this error is that complex types (e.g. `ARRAY`) require another type to be specified (cf. [SqlBase.g4](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.2.2/sql/catalyst/src/main/antlr4/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/parser/SqlBase.g4#L918-L926)):

```
dataType
    : complex=ARRAY '<' dataType '>'                            #complexDataType
    | complex=MAP '<' dataType ',' dataType '>'                 #complexDataType
    | complex=STRUCT ('<' complexColTypeList? '>' | NEQ)        #complexDataType
    | INTERVAL from=(YEAR | MONTH) (TO to=MONTH)?               #yearMonthIntervalDataType
    | INTERVAL from=(DAY | HOUR | MINUTE | SECOND)
      (TO to=(HOUR | MINUTE | SECOND))?                         #dayTimeIntervalDataType
    | identifier ('(' INTEGER_VALUE (',' INTEGER_VALUE)* ')')?  #primitiveDataType
    ;
```

In your case, it'd be as follows:

```
ARRAY<CHAR(3)>
```